# Numpy: change score to 4 GPA score

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to write a short code (maybe with the use of `numpy` or any other mathematical package) for calculating a score I recive in python according to the 4 GPA formola like in the [link](https://pages.collegeboard.org/how-to-convert-gpa-4.0-scale)

Means that, If Im receing this list of scores:

```
[95,100,80,42]
```

Ill receive this result:

```
[4.0,4.0,2.7,0.0]
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the specific attempt you've made so far at doing this and a detailed explanation of where you're stuck, thanks!

Comment: What have you tried based on your own research, and what went wrong with your attempts? Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] so that we can offer specific help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure NumPy solution using `np.digitize`:

```py
import numpy as np
scores = [95, 100, 80, 42, 39, 96, 80, 69]
bins = [64, 66, 69, 72, 76, 79, 82, 86, 89, 92, 96, 100]
gpa_scale = np.array([0.0, 1.0, 1.3, 1.7, 2.0, 2.3, 2.7, 3.0, 3.3, 3.7, 4.0, 4.0])
print(repr(gpa_scale[np.digitize(scores, bins, right=True)]))
```

Output:

```
array([4. , 4. , 2.7, 0. , 0. , 4. , 2.7, 1.3])
```

**EDIT:**
You can alternatively use `np.searchsorted`, which should be a faster since it does less checks on the inputs, the code is almost identical:

```py
import numpy as np
scores = [95, 100, 80, 42, 39, 96, 80, 69]
bins = [64, 66, 69, 72, 76, 79, 82, 86, 89, 92, 96, 100]
gpa_scale = np.array([0.0, 1.0, 1.3, 1.7, 2.0, 2.3, 2.7, 3.0, 3.3, 3.7, 4.0, 4.0])
print(repr(gpa_scale[np.searchsorted(bins, scores, side='left')]))
```

Output:

```
array([4. , 4. , 2.7, 0. , 0. , 4. , 2.7, 1.3])
```

**Complexity:**
Both `np.digitize` and `np.searchsorted` applies binary search to bin values, which results in a `O(nlogm)` worst case complexity. Whereas for loops and if checks has a `O(nm)` worst case complexity. Here `n` is the length of inputs, and `m` is the length of bins.

Answer (score -1):

```
list1 = [95, 100, 80, 42]


def GPA(inp):
    for i in list1:
        if i >= 90:
            print(4.0)
        elif i >= 80:
            print(3.0)
        elif i >= 70:
            print(2.0)
        else:
            print(1.0)


GPA(list1)
```

**output**

```
4.0
4.0
3.0
1.0
```

Here I have used a list and created a Function where it will check the condition and give output

Comment: doesn't cosider all the cases from the link